# Else statement to return to previous function

Tags: php

so I need to figure out how I can get my else statement to return to my previous function which is passprotect.html (the file I start on).
So I write in my password and click submit.
When I hit submit it checks with my PHP if the password is correct or not.
If the password is correct it writes "You did it!".
If it is wrong I want it to return back to the passprotect.html site with an error message saying, "Wrong password, try again!".

Here is my two codes:

```
<html>
<body>
<title>FriedBitz</title>

    <form action="secret.php" method="post">
    Password: <input type=password name=pass></input>
    <input type=submit value=Enter>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
<body>

HERE IS YOUR RESULT

<?php
    if ( $_POST['pass'] === 'test')
        {
        echo "You did it!";
        }
    else
        {
        header('Location:www.example.com');
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: So is header the wrong function to use? if so, what should I replace it with?

Comment: no. it's the correct function to use, but you're using it wrong. read the man page.

Comment: RTLM? Not familiar with that one

Comment: I can't seem to connect the page with my problem. I wish to return to the previous page, but add a error message aswell... How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as the Marc B noted you can not use header that way.

From the [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) -> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

If you have no option to change layout's of your project files (removing outputs before headers are sent) i suggest you to use ajax for this kind of work.

Or you need to place clickable link for user on a page instead of header.

Example of working header with your code:

```
        <?php
            if ( $_POST['pass'] === 'test')
                {
                $output = 'You did it!';
                }
            else
                {
                header('Location:www.example.com');
                exit;
                } ?> 
        <html> 
        <body>

        <?php echo $output; ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: But I have heard that Javascript does not give a safe solution to passwords, where as PHP does (or?). And what I wish to do is simply make a password for entering my personal website... and if the password is typed wrong, I want to have an error message appear, but if its right, I want to get redirected to the actual website address. Please not that I dont want to be able to avoid the passwords by typing in another URL. So the code has to be saved in cookies.

Comment: It worked arma, thank you! May I ask, would this be considered a safe way to have a password on my website?

Comment: @FriedBitz Well 1 password for website access is kind of easy to guess if you have generic password. Strength of authentication will improve also if you use login name + password. It will increase greatly also if you use some sort of mechanic to prevent multiple wrong entries from specified user. That so the user could not just run some password cracker on your authentication mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, I shall try implement some tries and time mechanism to it aswell, I dont want to use username as I simply just want to have 1 centered box in the middle of the page saying "Enter password".